# Type of Plasterboard to use in a bathroom?

Tags: bathroom, framing, studs

I'm installing a few framed/stud walls in a bathroom which will be covered in plasterboard and will eventually be tiled.

The walls are not going into a shower, bath or other area where they are likely to be in prolonged contact with water, so will I need to use moisture resistant plasterboard and stainless steel screws or will standard plasterboard/screws do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard drywall is just fine. In fact, as a builder we rarely used moisture-resistant drywall even above shower surrounds. Proper ventilation and good quality paints do the job just fine. We never had callbacks.

In my opinion, if you think you need moisture-resistant drywall, such as for tile backing, you should be using cementboard. Drywall of any type isn't appropriate for areas that regularly get splashed.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that, we've an MVHR system installed so hopefully that should keep the air fairly dry.

As for the showers, I'm using 12mm Hardiebacker and tanking them with Aquaseal liquid membrane.